# How can I implement a select-menu like on GitHub using JQuery?

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I want to implement a select menu like you use to switch branches on GitHub and described on this page https://github.com/styleguide/css/13.0 Specifically, I like how you can have multi-line items and also tabbed content.

How would you implement this using JQuery? Any plugins that would help?

Answer (score 0):

I want this element too (I need select with filter/search input field). I released [placecomplete](https://github.com/comerc/placecomplete) with select2 and selectize, but usability can be better.

Also I found [bootstrap-select](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) (`data-live-search="true"`)

Comment: Is it an answer or comment?